# How to pass main workbook to another macro function?

Tags: excel, vba

I have to macro function, where the second one calls for the first one in the loop.
I want to remember the main workbook and worksheet where the macro function was executed.

I wrote the following code%

```
Dim main_book As Workbook
Dim main_sheet As Worksheet
Set main_book = ActiveWorkbook
Set main_sheet = ActiveSheet
Dim table1 As Range

MsgBox main_book.Name
Set table1 = main_book.main_sheet.Range("A1", "J2")ˇ
```

But the last row returns an error, however if I hardcode the name of the workbook and worksheet everything works just fine. Can't find a solution and reason for this error

Comment: Do not specify the workbook if you already have a worksheet object. The worksheet is already defined as a member of a workbook.,

Comment: yes, `main_sheet.Range("A1", "J2")` NOT `main_book.main_sheet.Range("A1", "J2")`